# use columns of a CSV file using awk

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have a CSV file that contains paths, I want to copy the files of the first column in the paths of the second column How I manage to do that using awk for example if I have the following csv

```
project/file1     ../project1/file1.old
project/file2     ../project1/file2.old
project2/file1    ../project3/file1.old
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the csv file `src.csv` with following contents:

```
project/file1,../project1/file1.old
project/file2,../project1/file2.old
project2/file1,../project3/file1.old
```

Following is the linux command using `awk` and shell script which copies all the files mentioned in the csv:

```
awk -F "," '{print "cp " $1 " "  $2}' < src.csv > copy_src_dest.sh; sh copy_src_dest.sh
```